# How does the compositor interact with the 3d viewer? (Chroma keying movies as planes)

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am still new to Blender. I included movies with green screen on planes and am trying to chroma key them so they aren't green boxes moving around in 3d viewer. I know how to chroma key in compositor but I can't find a way to bring the texture from 3d viewer into the compositor and then take the output back into 3d viewer. Are 3d viewer and compositor even interactive with each other? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The 3D Viewport is the place where you can manipulate your models, and modify the way they look. You can use different shading techniques to see how your objects react in different scenarios.
It has a few "views" :

- Wireframe mode - Where you can see only the edges of your mesh, and can see through the faces
- Solid mode - The shading is simplified to help you focus on the geometry for example
- Lookdev mode - Where you can see an approximation of the final textured result thanks to the real-time render engine Eeevee
- Rendered mode - Where you see the scene as it will be rendered when you choose to output an image out of it. It is supposed to be slower so it is not recommended to use this mode when modifying your geometry

When you are happy with your rendered look, you can choose to render an image or a video of your scene. You need to add a camera and position it so that the parts you want to be in the final images are inside its field of view. You can see what will be rendered by pressing  <kbd>numpad 0</kbd> . When you are content with it, you then can render the image by pressing  <kbd>F12</kbd>  for a still image or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>F12</kbd>  for an animation (or go the render menu on top of the blender window).

Then the image is rendered, and you can add post-processing compositing effects, for example changing certain colors, adding flares or adding a vignette effect. This is a one-way process and can only be applied to rendered images. It cannot be used to then be applied back into the 3D viewport.

If you want a real-time chroma key you will have to build a custom shader for that, because the compositor will only affect the output of your rendered images.