# Where is the Chroma Key in Blender 2.92.0?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Using Blender 2.92.0 and I can only see the Keying Node in Compositing but not in Shading Nodes section. I watched a video of how to setup the chroma key green screen removal using Compositing and managed to successfully remove the green backdrop in the Compositing preview... but then what ? I still see the green screen image in Layout mode. I am not proficient with Compositing hence my confusion with the matter. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no need for a chroma key node in the shader editor hence no node. Recommend describe what you'd like to do rather just explaining your situation/confusion. Would you like to use the result as card in 3d view? What's your goal?

Comment: I thought I was describing the situation with my "how to setup the chroma  key green screen removal using compositing" in my initial comment. However I'll expand ..... I imported a short green screen video of a visual effect. I simply want to remove the green background. I saw someone using compositing which had the chroma key node to remove greens but I don't know how to then translate that green screen removal in compositing to show it's removal in the layout view and ultimately use it in the render. The layout view still shows the green screen with the visual effect in the imported video.

Comment: You would have to render the result to OpenEXR and [import it back in](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8191/31447) if you'd like to display the result in 3d view (layout view) for whatever reason. Usually that's not required, in most cases there is no reason having the footage in the viewport, you can just merge the rendering and the keyed footage in the compositor as a post process (the reason why I asked for your goal). Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165392/31447

Comment: This is the viewport layout video clip with green screen: [link] (https://i.paste.pics/bebc4ee835549134ca349f69ef08fd1a.png)  I did the following Compositor Node setup: [link] (https://i.paste.pics/04a362dcec1704c219bdc202abaca49c.png) [link] It seemed to have removed the green background. I rendered the compositor setup using the OpenEXR format. Then exported it in this format.

Comment: This format outputs a number of individual files. To import these to Blender, I used IMPORT then selected "Images as planes"  ... as I could not see the option for importing OpenEXR formats. I then saw in the viewport layout a string of these files appear.  [link] (https://i.paste.pics/04a362dcec1704c219bdc202abaca49c.png)   At this point I wasn't sure what to do now. I tried the video movie clip editor .. but didn't have much luck. Those links you provided .. to me .. were not specific with this last part of trying to formalize the transparency of the video clip by removing the green screen.

Comment: That's fine, It's a so called image sequence. Import only one image using Images as planes, go to the shader, set the image node to 'Image Sequence' and set the frames properly, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39876/movie-clip-on-plane

Comment: I imported one of the sequence OpenEXR images in Blender and then tried to work with it in Shader as per your instructions. However nothing changed. The link you provided was basic importing videos which I have already done as mentioned earlier in this discussion thread. As to the "set the frames properly".. not sure how as that link was not informative enough to explain it. I think I just might forget this and simply use other software I have to remove the green screen quickly and then import future blender exported creations into this software with the clip in question.

Comment: Blender developers really should introduce a simple quick green screen removal feature as it is a common feature in other software these days.

Comment: Why? Consider that Blender is no compositor like Nuke or Fusion. Is there any chroma keyer in Maya, Houdini or 3ds max? I don't think so. If you want it quick, I'd recommend do not try to import the sequence as a plane into the 3d scene, still not clear why you want this. As mentioned, just put your rendering on top of the keyed footage within the compositor. The linked q&a explains how to set that it up easily, you can do that manually of course. The only thing to change is Movie -> Image sequence. A movie would not work in your case because you'd have to encode to dnxhd or prores.

Comment: Hitfilm Express and VSDC video editor are just several examples of software that offer the chroma key removal feature. But concerning the reason as to why I want to work with this feature .... I want to be able to remove green screen short effect video clips and incorporate them in an imported image / scene and such things. I'm sure effects can be created with blender tools but I still want this option ... a very quick option to implement then manually creating an effect.

Comment: Just a quick question about the Blender video editor (somewhat relevant to this discussion) .... when editing a video .. for instance cropping it using mask feature, the same video (as a plane) in the 3D viewport layout (originally imported as a plane) does not change or get updated with the video editing changes on the 'fly'. If there is a way, that would help me quite a bit.

Comment: Can not help you out, never used the VSE... In other words: if you want it quick and in case it is necessary to place your footage onto a card in a 3d space, I suggest use a dedicated compositor like Fusion or Nuke. You can do the same in Blender, it just takes a long time to set it up properly (as we know by now) because Blender is actually 3d content creation tool. That there is a chroma keyer we can use, is just a bonus.

Comment: ok thanks for the info.